# value map isn't a member of int

Tags: scala

so I have the following simple code.
What I want to do is generate for a given list of tuples of (char , int)
another list as explained in the example:

For List((a,2),(b,1)), I want to have a list List( List((a,1)) ,List((a,2)), List((b,1))) .

```
val abba = List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
abba.map(elt=> for(t<-elt._2) yield (elt,t))
```

I tested my approach on the following snippet of code but I got the following error:

Error:(72, 31) value map is not a member of Int
    abba.map(elt=> for(t<-elt._2) yield (elt,t))

Any hints on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret your requirement correctly:

> For List((a,2),(b,1)), I want to have a list List( List((a,1))
>   ,List((a,2)), List((b,1)))

you can generate your list-of-list using `flatMap` and `for/yield` with input `1 to elt._2`:

```
val abba = List(('a', 2), ('b', 1))

abba.flatMap( elt => for(t <- 1 to elt._2) yield List((elt._1, t)) )
// res1: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List((a,1)), List((a,2)), List((b,1)))
```

Or, you can use `case` partial function as below:

```
abba.flatMap{ case (c, i) => for (j <- 1 to i) yield List((c, j)) }
// res2: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(List((a,1)), List((a,2)), List((b,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`for(t<-elt._2) yield (elt,t)` is equivalent to `elt._2.map(t => (elt, t))`. `elt._2` is the second element of the current tuple, so it's an integer. Integers do not have a `map` method, so the above can't work.

Looking at your expected output, it looks like you want to iterate `t` from 1 to `elt._2`. You can do that using the `to` method:

```
for(t <- 1 to elt._2) yield (elt._1, t)
```

It also looks like you want the first element of the original tuple to be the first element of the new tuples, so I added a `._1` as well.

As a style note, it might be a bit cleaner to use pattern matching on the tuple instead of `._1` and `._2`.